# Facebook Fan Page Tab "Review": posting via API?

Tags: facebook, api, review

I've got an awesome fan page on Facebook, used by my company for keeping customers in touch!

Now, I know how to post to the wall via Graph API and doing some other things.

I wonder if I can post to the **Reviews** area's wall: do you know what I mean?

Just below the profile pic, there's a little menu: the wall, informations, and the typical Facebook pages' **"tabs"**.

The "Reviews" tab is useful for accepting feedbacks from customers... What I'd like to do is automatically post the feedback/comments my customers leave on my website to this page-tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't possible.  You'd probably need to write your own "Reviews" app and add that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the reviews from the API via https://graph.facebook.com/appId/reviews but you cannot post a review from the API.  If you try to, you will get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException"
  }
}
```