# Creating pre-populated Review messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, messaging, facebook-wall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Fan Page Tab “Review”: posting via API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487808/facebook-fan-page-tab-review-posting-via-api)

Creating pre-populated Review messages

Hi, I have searched everywhere for a solution to create a pre-populated message when users submit reviews for my app, but I cannot locate how to do this, does anyone know?

Comment: I think it's a dup of http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7487808/facebook-fan-page-tab-review-posting-via-api

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you asking isn't exist.

The only access application have to reviews  is read access and for a good reason:
Review is something user think about app and do so, not the shining awesomeness app can pre-fill for those who doesn't mind clicking...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I see Zynga are able to do this with Farmville and promote the following message: Everything grows in FarmVille. Join your Facebook friends and live the rural dream. Play now! © 2011 Zynga Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Comment: Where are you seeing that? Are you sure it's a review?